# JSF InputText issue in DataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have problem with `InputText`. When I try to get the `InputText` value after clicking the button, the value is `null`.
When I create the login page, there isn't a problem but using a DataTable does.

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import model.Groups;
import model.Student;
import util.DataHolder;

@ManagedBean(name = "edit", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
@RequestScoped
public class EditController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Student> studentList;
private Groups group;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.group = DataHolder.getGroup();
}

public List<Student> getStudentList() {
    studentList = group.getStudents();
    return studentList;
}

public void saveGrade(Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.getName() + " " + student.getSurname() + "grade =" + student.getGrade());
}

public Groups getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Groups group) {
    this.group = group;
}

public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
    this.studentList = studentList;
}

}
```

---

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<title>Edit Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></link>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

```
<h:body>
<div class="container">
    <h:dataTable value="#{edit.studentList}" var="student"
        styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
        <h:column headerText="Student">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Student</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{edit.studentList.indexOf(student) + 1}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Number</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{student.no}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Name</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{student.name}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Surname</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{student.surname}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Grade</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:column>
                <h:form>
                    <h:inputText value="#{student.grade}" class="form-control"></h:inputText>
                </h:form>
            </h:column>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Save"
                    action="#{edit.saveGrade(student)}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"     value="Delete"
                    action="#{edit.deleteStudent(student)}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because the inputs are **not** in the same as the button. Only fields in the same form are submitted. Just put one form around the datatable

Comment: and a requestscoped AND sessioncoped on the same bean is not right

Comment: thanks alot :) its work.